# Is there a free tool for configuring WMS configuration xml?

Tags: qgis, wms, mapinfo

Instead of writing WMS xml file from scratch with notepad , is there a tool that is easy to create/configure such a file (or convert a GIS workspace - MapInfo / QGIS into WMS file) ?

Comment: I've read that one can export from QGIS to MapServer , but not sure how good is it and if there are other alternatives.

Comment: What WMS server are you using?

Comment: Currently mapxtreme , but looking to try free one (either ms4w or geoserver) thing is I'm a .net guy....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a tool exists. But you could probably easily create your own using .NET - I'm sure writing such a tool would be easier than maintaining the WMS config XML file by hand.

Of course that depends on how often you want to make changes to the service